# Cisco 1242 WAP Bridging

Tags: cisco, wifi, bridge, access-point

I'm looking to connect two facilities with a a pair of Cisco 1242 access points and am looking for advice on configuration.  We have multiple VLANs running that will need to be passed through the connection, but otherwise a fairly simple setup.  Any advice on best practices from security, reliability, and speed points of views?

Answer (score 0):

I think you made need to be more specific.  If you are asking about the Vlan portion you just need to configure a trunk with dot1q tagging on the router.  After you create the vlans in the DB, it is just something like:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.100.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.100.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
```